# php Get method is not getting the variable after & sign

Tags: php

my form contain this button and function `Redirect()` is redirecting to the another page and variable `$map_array` containing a `URL` that I am trying to get in another page but its  not displaying the value after the ampersand(`&`) sign.

```
<a onClick="Redirect();return false;" href="<?php echo $map_array[0][1]['deeplink']; ?>" 
style="background-color:#ff8c21;" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">
Buy Now</a>
```

Comment: use `&amp;` instead of `&` check [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: What is the Redirect() function doing. Please paste the whole code.

Comment: a onClick="return Redirect()"  instead of a onClick="Redirect();return false;"

Comment: What does `Redirect()` do? What is value of `$map_array[0][1]['deeplink']` ?